# node.js replace() - Invalid string length error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've just coded a little script to replace all variables from a .txt file to their values in a JS file

Example:

Txt file example (values):

```
Hi = "HELLO WORLD",
Hey = /someregex/g,
Hh = 'haha';
```

Script example:

```
window[Hi] = true;

"someregex hi".replace(Hey, "")

window[Hh] = 1;
```

Here's my script:

```
var fs = require("fs")


var script = fs.readFileSync("./script.js", "utf8");
var vars   = fs.readFileSync("./vars.txt", "utf8");

var replace = {}

var spl = vars.replace(/\r\n/g, "").replace(/        /g, "").split(",");

console.log("caching variables")

for(var dt of spl) {
    var splt = dt.split(" = ");

    var name = splt[0];
    var val  = splt[1];

    if(!name || !val) {
        continue;
    }

    if(val.endsWith(";")) {
        val = val.slice(0, -1);
    }

    replace[name] = val;
}

console.log("Variables are in cache!")
console.log("Replacing variables in script")

var i = 1;
var t = Object.keys(replace).length;

for(var var_name in replace) {
    var var_val = replace[var_name];
    var regex   = new RegExp(var_name, "g");

    console.log(i, "/", t, "Replacing", var_name, "with", var_val, "regex", regex)

    script = script.replace(regex, var_val);

    i++;
}

console.log("DONE!")

fs.writeFileSync("./dec.js", script, "utf8")
```

However, when `i ~= 100`, I have this error:

```
RangeError: Invalid string length
    at RegExp.[Symbol.replace] (native)
    at String.replace (native)
```

**EDIT: also, I can see that node.js process is using ~400MB of RAM and I have the error when it reaches 900MB**

What's wrong?

Comment: `window[Hi]` this is redundant. Just us the variable name `Hi`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know, but the script has defined all strings in the top of it, even the variables names, so it uses window[] for the variables